# Установка значения из ячейки в другую ячейку при соблюдении условия

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Сотрудники в начале смены выбирают свою фамилию из списка в ячейке `B1`. Необходимо, при установке в столбце `B` любого значения записать фамилию указанную в ячейке `B1` в столбец `C` (на одну ячейку вправо). Скрипт устанавливает дату в левый столбец, но не получается взять значение из ячейки

[image]

Пример: Сотрудник выбирают статус "Продажа", после чего следующий скрипт:

```js
function auto_set_date(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    if (sheet.getName() == "Касса") {
        var ar = sheet.getActiveRange();
        var a_col = ar.getColumn();
        if(a_col ===2 && ar.offset(0,-1).getValue()===""){
            var.offset(0,-1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3","dd.MM.yyyy")); 
        }
    }
}
```

устанавливает дату в столбец `A`.
Необходимо так же в столбец `C` установить фамилию менеджера который совершил редактирование значений в столбце `B`
[image]

Comment: Пришлите пример

Comment: Добавил в пост, надеюсь так более понятно

Comment: Добавил в пост скрипт который в данный момент ставит дату

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, может кому будет полезно

```js
function auto_set_name() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Касса") {
    let myCell = sheet.getRange("B1");
    let b1 = myCell.getValue()
    var ar = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var a_col = ar.getColumn();
    if (a_col === 2 && ar.offset(0, 1).getValue() === "") {
      ar.offset(0, 1).setValue(b1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Отметьте ответ как решение